# JavaFX won't import in BlueJ on Mac

Tags: java, javafx, bluej

I'm programming a music player in BlueJ for a school project, and I want to make use of a few classes from the JavaFX library. However, when I try to import (see import statements below), I get an error saying "javafx.scene.media does not exist". I have downloaded the latest JDK.

```
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
```

It should be noted that since it is a school project, I am obliged to use BlueJ, so switching to another IDE (in case that might be where the problem lies) is not an option.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

At present you'll need to add the JavaFX jar manually as a library - in the future this may change, but for now, go to Tools => Preferences, click on the "Libraries" tab, click "Add", then locate jfxrt.jar - it should be in your jdk directory, under `jre/lib`. When you're done, you'll get something like the following:

[image: BlueJ Preferences Dialog]

Reset your VM (Ctrl+shift+R) and then your import statements should work properly.